# Makie in Julia: keeping my axis labels but hiding the tickmark numbers

Tags: julia, heatmap, axis, axis-labels, makie.jl

I am trying to learn how to use Makie with Julia, I have only used Winston so far.
I am making a graph with latitude and longitude axis, and I want just their values on the axis, not the standard 1,5, and 10 that makie puts on all their axis. I also want to have my axis labeled, but I cant figure out how to separate the two -- to get rid of the numbers and keep the words. I am doing this in jupyter notebook.

I am importing netcdf data with multidimensional variables. I have already isolated the depth variable to one dimension for this. I have tried:

```
using NetCDF
using CairoMakie
using ColorSchemes

fig, axis, p=heatmap(lon1, lat1, h; labels=true, colormap=:rainbow_bgyrm_35_85_c71_n256)
Colorbar(fig[:, end+1], p, label="meters")
ax=Axis(fig[1,1], ylabel ="latitiude", xlabel="longitude", title="depth map",
leftspinevisible=false, bottomspinevisible=false, ticklabelvisible=false)
ax.aspect = 0.5
colsize!(fig.layout, 1, Aspect(1, 0.5))
display(fig)
```

and the graph I get is this :
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Npi.png)
on the axis' is my lat/long numbers, the makie axis numbers that I dont want, and the labels that I do want.

*Note: I get exactly the same looking graph with and without the code
`leftspinevisible=false, bottomspinevisible=false, ticklabelvisible=false`
in my axis command.*

Next I tried :

```
hidedecorations!.(ax)
display(fig)
```

Which only got rid of all the makie labels- both numbers and labels:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNTmf.png)
I have also tried adding the condition: `ticklabels=false` in the hide decorations code, after 'ax', still in parenthesis.

I have also already read through the documentation for labels and axis manipulation on the Makie webpage.

How can I keep the x/y labels while getting rid of the other numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing double ticks and labels because you are adding a new axis to the figure on top of the axis that is created when you call `heatmap`. To make modifications to the axis that you already created, you can write to the fields of the returned `axis`:

```
using CairoMakie
x = collect(1:10)
y = collect(1:10)
z = rand(10, 10)
fig, axis, p = heatmap(x, y, z)

axis.xlabel = "longitude"
axis.ylabel = "latitude"
axis.xticks = [2,3,5,7]
axis.yticks = 1:2:10

display(fig)
```

Another option is to first create the axis with the properties you desire where you want it in a figure, then use the `heatmap!` method (with the exclamation mark) to draw the heatmap in that axis:

```
using CairoMakie
fig = Figure()
axis = Axis(fig[1,1],
    xlabel = "longitude",
    ylabel = "latitude",
    xticks = [2,3,5,7],
    yticks = 1:2:10)

x = 1:10
y = 1:10
z = rand(10, 10)
heatmap!(axis, x, y, z)

display(fig)
```

These produce roughly the same figure:

[image: heatmap of 100 random random values in a 10x10 grid]